# How do I make a Zip-kick attack?

Tags: character-creation, powers, mutants-and-masterminds

In M&M, how do I mechanicaly create an attack that is my character grappling onto a surface, zipping towards it, then using the momentum to hit an opponent for an extra-powerful attack? (See Arkham City's Robin for a visual on what I'm talking about.)

Comment: Is this a core power for the character, or just something he can do if the circumstances allow (ie; something to zip on is present)?

Comment: And which edition?

Answer (score 2):

It depends on the edition. In 2E and 3E ([SRD entry](http://d20herosrd.com/9-gamemastering/8-action-adventure/#TOC-SLAM-ATTACK)), there's a mechanical way to do it with a *Slam* attack, which lets you potentially bypass the limits of PL at the cost of risking similar damage to yourself from the impact. You would be using *Speed* from your form of *Super-Movement* (*Swinging* with flawed *Speed* that only works with the *Swinging*).

You could also basically just build up your damage effect with either a *Quirk* or a *Flaw* for needing to move at the same time as attacking and describe it as the zip-kick. Whether it would be a *Quirk* or a *Flaw* depends on how limiting your GM feels it is for the attack to only work with a sufficient distance over which to move with your zip-line. If the utility is under 50% (50% of the time, it's not applicable, or it applies a similar level of disadvantage), it can make for a *Flaw*. If it's less than that, it's a *Quirk*, which might only get you a few points back. Lastly, you could probably get a few more points back if you keep part of the *Slam* attack descriptor by adding a *Side Effect*. Normally, *Side Effect* is either having to save against a commensurate effect if you fail (say, if you miss) for a -1 Flaw, or saving against a similar effect every time for -2. I'd think that always experiencing a half-effect would be worthy of a -1.

So you could always build onto your zipline *Device* / *Equipment* something like the following:
***Zipline Kick (Strength-Based Damage 4)*** (Quirk (Power Loss): Must combine with a move of at least 30 feet with the Zipline, Flaw (Side Effect): Always have to make a Toughness save against half the total damage done) [1 PP]

Of course, you could lastly simply do this by itself or in addition to the above as a matter of descriptors for your attack. *Power Attack* lets you add more damage at the cost of accuracy (useful for when you're attacking someone unawares of you and thus *Surprised*). *All-Out Attack* would let you sacrifice some defense for accuracy. The two together could readily describe swooping down to kick someone, hitting them with the same accuracy but greater power, but with the caveat that you're moving along a predictable arc, making it more likely you get tagged with return gunfire. *Move-By Attack* could reduce that risk by allowing you to move in, strike, and then get out and into the shadows, but would do less against things like prepared actions, or people able to target where you move into.

Lastly, if this is something you only do periodically, this could just be a textbook case of *Extra Effort* to raise the rank of your attack, possibly with the *Fatigue* being countered with the *Hero Point* your GM gives you for the cool description of swooping down to kick an opponent.

Comment: You could also potentially have the Device give you the Enhanced Advantage: Move-By Attack as part of the effects.  Then you would have Move-By Attack, but only when using the Zip-Line Kick (which makes sense if you don't normally have it).

Comment: Or just Power Attack.

Comment: @BrandonOlson: Yup. I mention that in my penultimate paragraph.

Comment: Okay, I see it now. It got a little lost.

Comment: @BrandonOlson: I modified the answer to highlight game terms.

Comment: @SeanDuggan Thank you, that makes it much more clear.